# Number by side of my username

Tags: support, bug, comments

I see a number being displayed by the side of my username on the comment [I just made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633611/what-are-the-key-differences-between-apache-thrift-google-protocol-buffers-mes#comment77833197_4633611). What's this number? views? flags?

[image]

Comment: Does it show "mins ago" on the next line, by any chance?

Comment: Lol :D, now I see, It was so mysterious at first.

Comment: so.. is this to be closed as no repro?

Comment: Maybe "mins ago" wasn't there at all. But after Jon's comment, the universe had to rearrange itself and inserted it there. Anyway, your problem is now solved.

Comment: The problem is not solved. The space between the number and the unit should be non-breaking.

Comment: Maybe OP should add "bug" tag.

Comment: To those voting to reopen, if you do so because you want this to be a bug report instead, pls take the time to actually make it a proper one.

Comment: @Bart Or maybe posting it as a new question.

Comment: Given the answer that would be advisable

Comment: [New feature-request posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354266/make-the-space-between-the-time-value-and-the-units-a-non-breaking-one). Now there's no reason to re-open this one.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, you could use your new powers to re-close this question :P.

Comment: Indeed, @Tom. Done. garg10may, please don't take this closure personally. Shadow Wizard has already answered your question, and while I think this is a valid feature-request/bug, that aspect of it kind of got hidden in the way this question was presented. (See previous comments by Bart and Maroun.)

Answer (score 12):

This is a rare case where your comment length caused the time stamp to overflow:

> [image]

Comment: There's also a weird red circle around the "secs ago". That's definitely a bug.

Comment: _circle_? O_O @MarounMaroun

Comment: @Sag well it's circular. ;-)

Comment: @SagarV [it's officially a circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/165773)