# Make the space between the time value and the units a non-breaking one

Tags: feature-request, design, comments, user-interface

In rare cases, a comment of a certain magical length will cause the time stamp to wrap onto the next line in [a confusing way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354192/number-by-side-of-my-username):

> [image]

<sup>(Image shamelessly stolen from Shadow Wizard, exploiting his hard work for my own gain.)</sup>

What happens here is that the number (in this case, "41") gets separated from the units (in this case, "seconds ago") when the text wrapping is performed.

Not only is this confusing, it is semantically incorrect. While it is correct to put a space between the value and the units, this space should *not* be a breakpoint for word wrapping.

This obviously isn't a terribly urgent issue, but the fix is a rather simple one: in the code that generates these timestamps, change the regular space to a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`).

Comment: Not terribly urgent but now it is over 5 years old :) I had just open a [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423209/prevent-line-breaks-in-comments-timestamps) so this FR gets my upvote! This sounds like a fairly easy task. Let's hope this gets in the pipe someday.