# Prevent line breaks in comments' timestamps

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Depending on the comment length, there will be a line break in the middle of the timestamp which makes it quite difficult to read.

I would think that using *non-breaking spaces* `&nbsp;` or applying a `white-space: nowrap;` CSS rule to the timestamp `<span>` element would make things better.

Current display:

[image]

With non-breaking spaces or no-wrap CSS rule:

[image]

Comment: Not sure whether this should be a bug, a feature request or just a discussion. Please feel free to edit.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request. AFAIK, it has never worked like you proposed, so it can't be a bug if that's the case

Comment: Ah I had searched but didn't find that one! Thanks

Comment: "it can't be a bug if [it has never worked]"... what?